# Foreign Key Not Mapped Correctly from Inheritance

Tags: entity-framework

If I have the following code generating my database it assigns a foreign key from the TankComponent table to the Asset table instead of the Tank table. Can someone explain why? Do I need to turn off a specific convention or change in the Fluent API? Is it really only looking at the column name?

```
[Table("Asset")]
public abstract class Asset
{
    [Key]
    public int AssetId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}


[Table("Tank")]
public class Tank : Asset
{
    public Tank()
    {
        this.TankCompnents = new Collection<TankComponent>();
    }

    public int TankField1 { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TankComponent> TankCompnents { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<Floor> Floors { get { return this.TankCompnents.OfType<Floor>(); } }
}


[Table("TankComponent")]
public abstract class TankComponent
{
    [Key]
    public int TankComponentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Tank")]
    public int AssetId { get; set; }
    public Tank Tank { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

//forgot this in initial post
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Tank>()
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.Properties(a => new { a.AssetId, a.Name, a.Description });
        m.Requires("AssetType").HasValue(1);
        m.ToTable("Asset");
    })
    .Map(m =>
        {
            m.Properties(t => new { t.AssetId, t.TankField1 });
            m.ToTable("Tank");
        });
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this with EF 5.0, .NET 4.0, SQL Express. I get the FK from `TankComponent` to `Tank` (I had to add a concrete class deriving from `TankComponent` to make the model valid. I guess you have such a class too.). What versions are you using?

Comment: I forgot to add my Fluent API code to this:
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Tank>()
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.Properties(a => new { a.AssetId, a.Name, a.Description });
                m.Requires("AssetType").HasValue(1);
                m.ToTable("Asset");
            }
            )
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.Properties(t => new { t.AssetId, t.TankField1 });
                m.ToTable("Tank");
            });
}

Comment: Yes, Slauma. I have a concrete class deriving from TankComponent. I am using EF 6.0 because I thought it would fix this issue. Had the same issue in 5.0

Comment: OK, this Fluent mapping seems to cause the issue. I can reproduce it now. Why do you have this mapping? For a TPT mapping it is not needed. This `AssetType` that you are adding is normally only used for TPH mapping as a discriminator column, but with TPT there is no  discriminator.

Comment: I need an Asset table in my database that stores common information because we will have more than one type of Asset, not just Tank. Does this require a type of "hybrid" between TPH and TPT? How would you go about doing this?

Comment: But EF will create an `Asset` table also without your mapping (because of your `[Table]` attributes). Common properties would be properties in class `Asset` and they all go into the `Asset` table without further mapping. The properties declared in `Tank` go into their own table and the same for other derived classes. Maybe I misunderstand your question, but right now I don't see a problem...

Comment: When I go and add a public DbSet<Asset> Asset { get; set; } and then try and create a Tank (Tank tank = new Tank() { Name = "Tank1" }; tankContext.Tank.Add(tank); tankContext.SaveChanges();) I get a null reference exception.

Comment: Seems to be a different problem. I can't reproduce that. Can you analyze more details? If you can't find anything I suggest to create a new question and provide the stack trace, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mapping line...

```
m.Requires("AssetType").HasValue(1);
```

...and your comments seem to indicate that you possibly have a misunderstanding how Table-Per-Type (TPT) inheritance works.

EF does not need a specific column in the table of the base class `Asset` to detect what the actual type of the entity with a given primary key value is - unless you would use Table-Per-Hierarchy (TPH) inheritance mapping (i.e. a mapping without having `[Table]` attributes on your entities). For TPH a specific column - the discriminator - in indeed necessary to distinguish between the types because all properties of all entities in the inheritance tree would be stored in a single table. If you don't specify a discriminator explicitly - like `AssetType` - EF would create a column called `Discriminator` by default.

Now, TPT is a different story. If you query an entity that has other derived entities - for example...

```
var asset = context.Assets.First();
```

...EF will not only create a SQL query like `SELECT TOP(1) * FROM ASSETS` on the base table alone but instead a - possibly very complex - query with many `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s to many other tables that belong to all possible derived entities. This query would either find a row in the `Tank` table or not. If it does find one EF will materialize a `Tank` object. If not it will materialize an `Asset`. (Cannot be the case here because `Asset` is `abstract` but assume for a moment it would *not* be `abstract`.) If `Asset` has other derived types EF will join their tables as well and decide again about the concrete entity type depending on the existence of joined rows.

So, with TPT the type is detected not by a special column but only by the result of (left outer) table joins.

The line above seems to confuse EF somehow. But it really doesn't belong into a TPT mapping and I would remove your whole mapping with Fluent API.

I've tested that the result is correct when you remove the mapping - i.e. the FK relationship will be created between `TankComponent` and `Tank` table (not `Asset` table).

Comment: Thanks for you explanation! I am very new to EF code-first and specifically the TPH and TPT concepts. I really appreciate your comments. When you say you tested the results, did you get the tables created in your database (including the Asset table)?

Comment: @stumpykilo: Yes, an `Asset` table for the base properties and a `Tank` table for the derived properties.